# How to run raw query in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

How can I write the below raw query in Laravel

```
 $result=  DB::select('SELECT a.awb_number,a.full_awb_number,a.service_type, b.city AS From_city, c.country_code AS From_country, b.city AS To_city, c.country_code AS To_country, datediff( max(s.created_at), min(s.created_at)) as Aging FROM customer_shippments a LEFT JOIN addresses b ON a.from_address = b.id LEFT JOIN addresses c ON a.to_address = c.id LEFT JOIN statuses s ON s.awb_number = a.awb_number WHERE a.full_awb_number IN ("LA172827289EE", "LA172828854EE", "LA172829894EE") GROUP BY s.awb_number');
   return $result;
```

While executing the above query I am getting the following error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'track.a.awb_number' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: SELECT a.awb_number,a.full_awb_number,a.service_type, b.city AS From_city, c.country_code AS From_country, b.city AS To_city, c.country_code AS To_country, datediff( max(s.created_at), min(s.created_at)) as Aging FROM customer_shippments a LEFT JOIN addresses b ON a.from_address = b.id LEFT JOIN addresses c ON a.to_address = c.id LEFT JOIN statuses s ON s.awb_number = a.awb_number WHERE a.full_awb_number IN ("LA172827289EE", "LA172828854EE", "LA172829894EE") GROUP BY s.awb_number)
```

Comment: What DBMS do you use?

Comment: MySQL database management

Answer (score 1):

This error may occur, if you have parameter
`'strict' => true`
in config/database.php for you DB connection.

You can set this parameter to false, or change your query so that all the fields from 'select' are represented in 'group by'

Comment: i have set the parameter 'strict'=> false but didnt worked

Comment: @user5370838, please, check, maybe your DB settings has `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` parameter. To check this, run ```SELECT @@sql_mode;``` query and check has the result ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY or not. If has, you can disable this using ```SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));``` query

Comment: @ Andrew Markhai i tried with this raw query it worked sir....tq so much for ur support public static function getstatusData(){

        return DB::connection('mysql')->select('SELECT a.awb_number,a.full_awb_number,a.service_type, b.city AS From_city, b.city AS To_city, datediff( max(s.created_at), min(s.created_at)) as Aging FROM customer_shippments a LEFT JOIN addresses b ON a.from_address = b.id WHERE a.full_awb_number IN ("LA172827289EE", "LA172828854EE", "LA172829894EE") GROUP BY s.awb_number');
      }

Answer (score 1):

use **DB::raw()**, but try to sanitize your data first before use DB::raw to prevent SQL Injection

```
$result = DB::raw('select blablabla')->get();
return $result;
```

[Laravel Query Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries)